# Tibbo Serial to/over Network на linux с net-core

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, com-порт, ethernet

Проблема следующая: есть устройство типа Tibbo - преобразователь `Serial Port to Ethernet`, с одной стороны к нему подключается RS-485, с другой Ethernet, устройство Tibbo преобразует COM-данные в свой протокол, а на стороне компьютера устанавливается драйвер, который заводит виртуальный COM-порт, который соединяется по Ethernet с данным устройством и обратно преобразует данные.
Проблема в том, что к виртуальному COM-порту необходимо подключаться через приложение .NetCore 3.1 под linux, а драйвер для устройства Tibbo (VSPDL driver офф сайт https://docs.tibbo.com/soism/vspl_installation) не совместим новыми версиями ядра.
В итоге у нас .Net Core 3.1, которому для работы нужен Ubuntu 16.04 (kernel 4.4) и новее, а офф версия драйвера Tibbo требует kernel 2.6.x (Ubuntu 12.04) и более старые.

Поиск альтернативных драйверов как и библиотек к успеху не привёл.

**Если кто-нибудь знает какой-нибудь nuget пакет/библиотеку, с помощью которых можно сконнектиться с устройством прямо по Ethernet (TCP Client) и читать/писать данные в виде COM, или известен совместимый драйвер с Ubuntu 16.04 или новее - подскажите пожалуйста.**

Comment: Использовать Mono на старой Убунте?

Comment: Какой свой протокол? 99.9% всех этих serial2Ethernet никакой магии не используют, просто тупо транслируют данные в байт поток по сети. Вы `socat` пробовали?

Comment: Если же ваша железка попала в категорию 0.1% (и это подтверждено различными экспериментами, хотя я в это не верю), то грош цена этой груде металла, замените железку.

Comment: И вообще, пробуйте гуглить иногда https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/general/12659604

Answer (score 0):

`sudo socat pty,link=/dev/virtualcom0,raw tcp:IP_ADDRESS:1001`
Правда решение проблемное, далеко не все программы могут подключиться к порту. Как-раз .NET Core кажется не может.
Пока Socat запущен - порт доступен.
Можно добавить в Systemd с авторестартом.

На сайте производителя есть исходники (драйвера или утилиты), которые периодически обновляются, есть возможность откомпилить под 5ю версию ядра.